# Abrir aplicación UWP Desktop Bridge mediante toast

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp

He desarrollado una aplicación WPF la cual he convertido a UWP mediante el Desktop App Converter y funciona bien.

Le he añadido notificaciones toast llamando a APIs universales como se explica aquí https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/10/16/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10/

Pero para que la aplicación se abra automáticamente cuando el usuario pulsa sobre la notificación, he tenido que crear un acceso directo en Inicio y registrar un componente COM de la misma forma que en https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts

Creo que es demasiado trabajo comparado a una UWP completa donde el comportamiento por defecto es justo ese, abrir la aplicación automáticamente sin escribir código.

¿Cómo podría hacer que mi aplicación UWP convertida mediante el Bridge, se abra pulsando la notificación toast, al igual que si fuera una UWP normal?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar? Saludos